# Update google cloud composer withterragrunt

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-composer, terragrunt

I am trying to update cloud composer from `composer-1.17.3-airflow-1.10.14` to `composer-1.17.10-airflow-1.10.15` using terragrunt. 
After one hour it fails with the message:

```
Upgrade database failed.
Error: Error waiting to update Environment: Error waiting for Updating newly created Environment: Error code 9, message: Failed to update image version.
```

I already checked the logs and the recommendations on the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/troubleshooting-updates-upgrades?hl=en) (database is less than 16 GB, that the PyPI packages are compatible and that I can use the correct version for the upgrade)

Any help is appreciated!